# Select call sets the server's socket when a client disconnects

Tags: c, sockets, select, server, client

I was playing around with a server with multiple clients in C and noticed one thing: Whenever a client disconnect from the server (The server simply calls close on the client's file descriptor), a select call (I'm using select to handle messages from multiple clients) sets the server's socket as ready to read from and the return value of the call is 0. Ignoring this fact blocks the server because select keeps returning 0 with the server socket set as ready instead of waiting for other sockets. Is there some extra clean-up to be done with the server socket after someone disconnected and before the server can accept new connection?

Answer (score 1):

When your server gets 0 or -1 from `recv()` it should call close on that socket, further is should ensure this socket is removed from read and write fdsets that are passed to `select()` otherwise select() will return error indicating there is a bad fd present in its read/write fdsets

Comment: Thank you very much! It turned out that I was checking the wrong flag when adding sockets to fdsets